# Программа зависает из-за функции в отдельном потоке

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь получить ID друзей из ВК. Получаю json, перебираю всё и заношу в textbox. Но почему то, во время появление ID (id-шников примерно 2500) в textBox программа зависает, хотя вроде всё в фоне и в отдельном потоке. Что можно сделать, что бы программа не висла?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread myThread = new System.Threading.Thread(get_friends_id);
            myThread.Start();
        }
        void get_friends_id()
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?v=5.8&user_id=1");
                HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
                string vk_get = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                if (vk_get == null || vk_get == "")
                {
                    BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => MessageBox.Show("Ошибка получения данных от сервера")));

                }
                else
                {
                    JObject json_vk_get = JObject.Parse(vk_get);
                    if ((string)json_vk_get["response"]["count"] == null || (string)json_vk_get["response"]["count"] == "")
                    {
                        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => MessageBox.Show("Ошибка получения данных от сервера")));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (string value in json_vk_get["response"]["items"])
                        {
                            BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => textBox1.Text += value + Environment.NewLine));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: А где и что именно висит? Попробуйте отладочную печать (`Debug.WriteLine`) в нужных местах.

Comment: Висит вся программа , в момент вывода ID 
BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => textBox1.Text += value + Environment.NewLine));

Comment: @MadKeks: Хм. Странно. `Control.BeginInvoke` (у вас же winforms, да?) просто отправляет код на выполнение в UI-поток в стиле fire-and-forget. Это _не может_ завесить программу, и _не может_ завесить ни рабочий, ни UI-поток. Всё-таки добавьте отладочную печать. Очень не верится, что рабочий поток не выходит из `BeginInvoke` (разве что вы делаете что-то очень неправильное в остальной части программы).

Comment: Ладно, решил пойти в обход. Собрать всё в 1 переменную и потом вывести. Так ни чего не висит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поток UI,скорее всего, вешает

`BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => textBox1.Text += value + Environment.NewLine)));`

Попробуйте сначала собрать значения для `textBox1`, например в `StringBuilder`, а потом уже указать текст для `textBox1`:

```
BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => textBox1.Text = stringBuilder.ToString());
```

Где `stringBuilder` - переменная типа `StringBuilder`